# Algorithm for conversion of MathML to AsciiMath and Latex to MathML

Tags: latex, mathml, asciimath

I need to convert LaTeX code to Mathml and Mathml to asciimath. Is there any algorithm or javascript code present to convert that. I don't want to use node packages.